# User login/logout button in menu Angular 8 not updating

Tags: angular, authentication, menu, page-refresh

I have a `mat-toolbar` with a login/logout button where the user of the website can login or out at all times. I have an authentication service which creates an Observable with user data and using `*ngIf="!(authService.user$ | async)` for the login button. This isn't working though, unless I manually refresh the whole page. Why is this and what does one do about it? I thought the Observable would be a way that would actually work in these situations, but obviously I am missing something.

I have also tried subscribing to the Observable as `user` in **app.component.ts** and using `user` in the template, but this doesn't seem to help. I know there are several questions regarding user login with Observables, and questions about refresh, but they haven't given me an understanding of why this isn't working.

I should perhaps add that I am using an interface `User` with property `roles`, for role based authorisation, so it is not the same as `firebase.User`.

Relevant parts of **authentication.service.ts**:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthenticationService {
  user$: Observable<User>;
  viewAllUser: Boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router) {

    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`Users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
        } else {
          return of(null)
        }
      }))
  }

  /* Sign up */
  SignUp(email: string, password: string) {
    this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        window.alert("You have been successfully registered!");
        this.updateUserData(result.user)
        //console.log(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message);
        //console.log(error.user);
      });
  }

  /* Sign in */
  SignIn(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        window.alert("You have been successfully signed in!");
        this.updateUserData(result.user);
        //console.log(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message);
        //console.log(error.user);
      });
  }

  /* Sign out */
  SignOut() {
    this.router.navigate(['user-main']);
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    window.alert("You have been successfully signed out!");
  }

 private updateUserData(user) {
        // Sets user data to firestore on login
        const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`Users/${user.uid}`);
        const data: User = {
          uid: user.uid,
          email: user.email,
          roles: {
            role1: true //default role
          }
        }
        return userRef.set(data, { merge: true }) //Update in non-destructive way 
      }
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<body>
  <mat-toolbar>
    <span>
      <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="!(authService.user$ | async) as user" routerLink="/user-main">Login</button>
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="authService.SignOut()" routerLink="/user-main" *ngIf="authService.user$ | async">Logout</button>
      {{user.email}} //for testing
    </span>
    <span>
      <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </span> 
  </mat-toolbar>
  <mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
    <!-- Only to be shown to logged in users: -->
    <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="authService.user$ | async" routerLink="/user-main">User main</button>
    <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="authService.user$ | async" routerLink="/page_x">Page X</button>
    <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="authService.canViewData(authService.user$ | async)==true" routerLink="/secret_page_y">Secret page Y</button>
  </mat-menu>

  <!--This is where the routes are shown-->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</body>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from './shared/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  user;

  constructor(public authService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.authService.user$.subscribe(user => this.user = user);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `BehaviorSubject` for the user and use it like :

authentication.service.ts:

```
    private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>({} as User);
    public currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

  getCurrentUser(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }
      /* Sign up */
      SignUp(email: string, password: string) {
        this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then((result) => {
            window.alert("You have been successfully registered!");
            this.updateUserData(result.user);
            //console.log(result.user);
          }).catch((error) => {
            window.alert(error.message);
            //console.log(error.user);
          });
      }

      /* Sign in */
      SignIn(email: string, password: string) {
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then((result) => {
            window.alert("You have been successfully signed in!");
            this.updateUserData(result.user);
            //console.log(result.user);
          }).catch((error) => {
            window.alert(error.message);
            //console.log(error.user);
          });
      }


      private updateUserData(user) {
        // Sets user data to firestore on login
        const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`Users/${user.uid}`);
        const data: User = {
          uid: user.uid,
          email: user.email,
          roles: {
            role1: true //default role
          }
        }
        this.currentUserSubject.next(data); // --> here
        return userRef.set(data, { merge: true }) //Update in non-destructive way 
      }
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
this.authService.currentUser.subscribe(user => this.user = user);
```

auth-guard.service.ts:

```
const user = this.authService.getCurrentUser();
if (user.id) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details! I'm having an error at `this.currentUserSubject.next(result.user);` due to the fact that instead of using `firebase.User` as `User`, I have made my own interface `User`, which includes the property `roles`. Atm I can't think of a good way around this...

Comment: Can't understand your problem if you don't post error details. Maybe you need to put this.currentUserSubject.next(result.user); in your updateUserData() method if you map your model there ?

Comment: Of course. "Argument of type 'firebase.User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("[PATH]/shared/user").User'.
  Property 'roles' is missing in type 'firebase.User' but required in type 'import("[PATH]/shared/user").User'."

Comment: Oh wow, thanks ever so much! This got it to work! (Btw, I realised I also needed to add something in my SignOut() method: `this.currentUserSubject.next(null);`)

Comment: A follow up question, if you don't mind.. I am using a guard with canActivate method. Should I use the Observable `currentUser` there, or the BehaviorSubject `currentUserSubject`? I can't seem to get any one of them to work, apart from the BehaviorSubject after page refresh which I find strange...

Comment: Thanks again, really kind of you! It's working! I had some problems because I retrieved the user roles from Firestore in my authService constructor. After moving this to the signup/signin functions, it seems to be working. Still have some problems with the user data though in general, because it seems to disappear on page refresh. I guess this is a different question though. Maybe it could have to do with me unsubscribing to `currentUser` at ngOnDestroy in various places...